# Is it possible to integrate Keras and TensorFlow code?

Tags: keras, tensorflow

I want to use the pre-trained VGG16 model of Keras, along with another TensorFlow model. I want to take the output from one of the layers of VGG16 in Keras, put it into the TensorFlow model and train only the latter. Is this possible if I use a TensorFlow backend for Keras?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Perhaps this may help you: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UeheTiBJ0Io

Comment: Keras is now officially part of TF, so it seems possible

Answer (score 2):

---

A naive approach to integrate Keras and Tensorflow:

```
input_img = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (1,200,300,3), name='input_img')
vgg19 = tf.keras.applications.VGG19(weights='imagenet', include_top=False)
output = vgg19(input_img)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    output_val = sess.run(output, {input_img: 
                          np.expand_dims(img,0)})

output_val.shape, output_val.mean()
```

Comment: vgg16.predict()

Answer (score 2):

I believe you must be able to employ `K.function` to get an intermediate tensor from the Keras model. Something like that:

```
input_tensor = Input(shape=(224, 224, 3))                                                                                                                                                                                               
base_model = VGG16(input_tensor=input_tensor, weights='imagenet')                                                                                                                                                                       

for layer in base_model.layers:                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    layer.trainable = False                                                                                                                                                                                                             

model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=base_model.get_layer('block4_pool').output)                                                                                                                                              
keras_model_output = K.function([model.input, model.output])
```

Then, build a Tensorflow model on the top of the `keras_model_output` and train as usual.